# configuring the root url for a Heroku Grails app

Tags: grails, heroku, jetty

I'm using the Grails stack on Heroku to deploy an app.  I'd like to be able to serve my app with a root of `myapp.herokuapp.com/xyz` as opposed to `myapp.herokuapp.com`, in the same way I'm able to serve from root of `localhost:8080/xyz` in development. I've tried adding a `grails.app.context` in Config.groovy like so:

```
environments {
    production {
            grails.app.context = "/xyz"
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to have an effect in deployment. Do I have to configure something with Heroku? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have to add a `jetty-web.xml` file to the `WEB-INF` directory to set the context path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- File: web-app/WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml -->
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath">/xyz</Set>
</Configure>
```

If this helps proper credit goes to [this](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/12/grails-goodness-change-context-path-of.html) site, which was linked from an article on [Grails and Heroku](http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/grails-on-heroku/) by Tomas Lin.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work as written on Heroku. I created `/web-app/WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml` and pasted the above, get a 404 hitting `/xyz` in prod. I'm wondering if Heroku is seeing and using that `jetty-web.xml` file when it starts the app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set context path with the current [Grails build pack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-grails). If you feel like it, you can fork the build pack and hack it to support setting context (see [build pack doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) for more info on build packs).

Another option is to build your Grails app locally into a WAR file and deploy the WAR file using [WAR deployment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment). The WAR deployment process will use the [webapp-runner](https://github.com/jsimone/webapp-runner) utility to run your app with Tomcat and it supports configuring the context path. Here's the help output for webapp-runner 7.0.22.3 (what I happened to have installed, might be slightly out of date):

`Tomcat Runner runs a Java web application that is represented as an exploded war in a Tomcat container
Usage: java -jar tomcat-runner.jar [arguments...] path/to/webapp
Arguments:
--session-timeout             The number of minutes of inactivity before a user's session is timed out

--port                        The port that the server will accept http requests on

--context_xml                 The parth to the context xml to use

--path                        context path (default is /)

--session_manager             session store to use (valid options are 'memcache')

--session_manager_operation_timeoutoperation timeout for the memcached session manager. (default is 5000ms)

--session_manager_locking_modeSession locking mode for use with memcache session store. (default is all)

--session_manager_ignore_patternRequest pattern to not track sessions for. Valid only with memcache session store. (default is '.*\.(png|gif|jpg|css|js)$'`

As explained in the [WAR deploy doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment), you can set webapp-runner options for your webapp using the `WEBAPP_RUNNER_OPTS` config var.